# How to handle data event from Tcp-Client with NestJs

Tags: tcp, nestjs

Im building the TCP app with Nestjs but I get the problems: How can I handle data event  because Nestjs TCP just support EventPattern and MessagePattern.

This is client.js

```
const net = require('net');

const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(12345, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('Connected');
  client.write(Buffer.from(['0x32']));
});
```

This is server from Js ( Just for demo how can handle data from Client )

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.write(Buffer.from(['0x32', '0x33', '0x34', '0x35']));
  socket.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  console.log('Microservice is listening');
});
```

And This is Controller, How can I handle `data` event in Nestjs, thats mean how can I apply some functions like socket.on('data') in Nestjs

```
@MessagePattern('How to use data event')
  async createDeviceEvnt(data: any) {
    console.log('sdasdasd');
  }
```

Comment: Do you or anybody else have a solution for this?